# How can I get 'online store' Sales channels product in shopify?

Tags: php, api, shopify

I want to check the product is available on the online store on Shopify or not. While adding the product in the Shopify we have an option in the sales channel -> 'online store'. I want to check that my product is available in `online sales` or not. Also list of products available in `online sales`.

I have reviewed below Links to get `online store` means sales channels products. But not it's not working.
https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/sales-channels/productlisting

https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-sales-channels#available-online-sales-channels

I have also attached the reference images below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPX6S.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get it like that. You need to use products API and verify if `published_at` field has a value.

More details - https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products/product